# New Nexus 4 - transfer photos and other stuff from old Nexus S

Tags: backup, samsung-nexus-s, images, nexus-4

So obviously I can't just "swap the SD card" as neither the old phone nor the new phone have an SD card slot.

Similarly I don't really want to copy everything across from the old phone, so I don't want to use titanium backup and root.

I just want the "standard" stuff transfered: mainly images, but maybe text messages and such as well.

Is there any way to do this short of literally plugging the phone into a computer and transferring them manually?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35580/how-can-i-transfer-photos-to-my-android-jelly-bean-device-while-preserving-the-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sync should take care of contacts and most settings on your phone.

Download [SMS Backup and Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en) on both phones, backup on Nexus S and send the backup xml file to N4 (via Bluetooth or wifi hotspot) for restoration.

For transferring files between the devices, you can use the wifi hotspot functionality. Works real fast. I'm not sure if it is available on Nexus 4 (being a newer, better phone, I presume it is), but I have it on my Nexus S and have used it to transfer files from a Galaxy S2.

*Update:* [AnySend](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=adylitica.android.anysend) seems like a useful app to send files between two devices. The only requirement is that both have to be connected to the same wifi network.

Comment: Pretty good. I just went through my SD card in the end and found all my pictures and stuff I wanted to save. The SMS backup and restore app was really useful for SMS. Thanks!