# New phone : migrate pictures and videos?

Tags: sync

Alright, I just got my new oneplus one (replacing my old samsung). To get startes, i just need to get pictures copied to my new phone.

Not as easy as i thought!

1) google plus does not "recover" images to my new phone. It just lets med see images from my old phone via the net. Not good enough.

2) most sync apps (i've tried about 10 og them) syncs files, but fails to sync timestamps. For images this is fine (exif data is used), but all videos appear as being filmed today on my new device.

How do i get images and videos to my new phone WITH timestamps preserved?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not sth in your hand to modify easily, but i've found some tricky solutions you can use.

At first take a look at a pre-asked related question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35580/how-can-i-transfer-photos-to-my-android-jelly-bean-device-while-preserving-the-o).

The second way which is a kinda boring is to use [File Timestamp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.pogsoftwares.filetimestamp&hl=en) to rewrite your own custom time metadata on any file you want.

hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible for you to connect your old phone to a computer, navigate to the photos directory and copy them over to your computer.

After that, connect your shiny new OnePlus One and copy the images over.

This should preserve all the EXIF data including the timestamp

Comment: Dragging files from one device to the other will not preserve timestamps..