# Does migration of whatsapp images and videos from google drive preserve file modification date?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive, date-and-time

According to [this Android Stackexchange answers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35580/how-can-i-transfer-photos-to-my-android-jelly-bean-device-while-preserving-the-o) file modification dates aren't restored upon restoration. So videos and images restored from Google Drive backup of whatsapp won't work leading to incorrect sorting. This is an error in the filesystem drivers called FUSE and won't be fixed till Android O.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the file system modification date is updated to the current date somehow whatsapp whether through the EXIF date picture taken tag or database it keeps the original date thus preserving sort order.